# Using USB to IDE converter from external hard disk with DVD drive

Tags: power-supply, usb, ide

My current laptop no longer has an optical drive. Since I have a spare IDE DVD drive and a 500 GB Western Digital Bookcase external HD sitting around, I thought of ripping the USB to IDE converter from the hard disk drive and hooking it up to the DVD drive. The converter also has a power connector for the drive.

However, when I put the whole thing together and hook it up to my laptop, it doesn’t work. The tray will open and close when I press the button. When I insert a disk, the drive will start spinning up but then stay silent (either spinning at a very low speed, or stopping altogether). The file manager on my laptop (Caja on Ubuntu MATE) does not show an optical drive, either with or without a disk inserted.

My guess is that is it one of the following:

- The USB to IDE adapter can only handle hard disks, but not optical drives.
- The drive draws more current than the power supply is capable of.

My next thought was to hook up the drive to a separate power supply (e.g. one from an old parallel port CD-ROM I still have lying around), while still powering the USB converter.

Is there any risk of the two separate power supplies causing any harm to the components involved? (Provided they supply the power specified.)

How else could I troubleshoot the issue (without using any lab equipment more sophisticated than a basic multimeter)?

Comment: Just buy an external optical drive for your laptop. They're like $30.

Comment: @Toor Even as little as $10 if you don’t need DVD write capabilities. But then, the homebrew solution costs close to zero if I get it to work :-)

Comment: And spend hours trying to get it to work. I also don't think it's a guarantee that any old USB to IDE adapter will work with any kind of drive.

Comment: Spinning at low speed makes "not enough current available" extremely probable. There are plenty of USB-IDE adapters that allow external power supplies (I have two of those), so unless your particular USB-IDE adapter does something unusual, an external power supply should just work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the drive, as Jasen suggested, indeed reveals that the DVD drive draws 1.5 A on both legs whereas the HD requires just 0.68 and 0.55 A respectively. So the power supply may be indeed too weak.

However, even when I power the drive from a PC power supply (while still powering the USB converter), I get the same behavior. The tray opens and closes but the drive does not spin up, and does not appear in the file manager. `lsusb` shows me a WD Bookcase HD device, though.

So apparently the USB converter is not generic enough to work with optical drives.

Answer (score 1):

IDE has all the power on the translucent white Molex(tm) connector if you disconnect that connector from the USB enclosure and substitute another power supply there is no risk of damage.

There will be a label on the drive that states what its power requirements are

The USB converter will require power to do its conversion, there is a possibility that this feature can be powered over the USB cable, but it may require external power to operate.